# Concentration result for self-normalized empirical process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, st.statistics, measure-concentration

In Theorem 1.1 of this [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-30/issue-4/Concentration-inequalities-large-and-moderate-deviations-for-self-normalized-empirical/10.1214/aop/1039548367.full) by Bercu, Gassiat and Rio, a concentration result is derived for the 'self-normalized' empirical process. Specifically, suppose that $(X,X_n)_{n \ge 1}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables, and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a class of functions that is

1. Centered: $\mathbb{E} f(X) = 0$ for every $f \in \mathcal{F}$
2. Normalized: $\mathbb{E} f^2(x)=1$ for every $f \in \mathcal{F}$
3. Countable

Define the random variable $W_n(f) = \frac{P_n(f)}{\sqrt{P_n(f^2)}}$ where $P_n$ denotes expectation with respect to the empirical measure.

Then, for any $\delta>0$, $\alpha > \sqrt{2}$, there exist $\theta>0, n_0$ depending on $\mathcal{F}, \alpha, \delta$ such that for all $n \ge n_0$ and any $x \in [0, \theta \sqrt{n}]$

$$
\mathbb{P}(\sqrt{n} \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} W_n(f) \ge x + \alpha E) \le 2 \exp (-\frac{x^2}{4\alpha^2 (1+\delta)}).
$$
Here, $E$ is a quantity that captures the complexity of the underlying class $\mathcal{F}$.

I have two questions about this theorem:

1. The assumption of countability seems a bit odd to me compared to other results in empirical process theory and I was hoping to apply this result to a (uncountably) infinite family $\mathcal{F}$. Is this assumption just another way of stating the more common assumption that the process $(W_n(f))_{ f \in \mathcal{F} } $ is separable? or is it deeper than that? Recall that if a process $X(t)$ indexed on a continuous set $t \in T$ is separable, then there exists a finite set $T_0 \subset T$ such that
   $$
   \mathbb{E} \sup_{t \in T} X(t) = \mathbb{E} \sup_{t \in T_0} X(t).
   $$
2. The statement of the theorem relies on some $\theta$ which the authors claim depends on the underlying function class. How can we then use this result if we don't know how $\theta$ is defined? It seems important to the result and is left un-stated.

Comment: 1. The countability is needed to ensure that $\sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} W_n(f)$ be measurable. 2. There are almost infinitely many qualitative results with unspecified (say) constants. In some cases, it might be possible to get explicit bounds on such constants following the lines of the proof, but such bounds would in most cases be rather poor. 3. There should be only one question in one post.

Comment: @IosifPinelis regarding the bounds on constants - I understand that this is generally the case for truly universal constants, but here it seems to be that the constant $\theta$ depends on the underlying function class so it seems a bit strange. I understand that countability makes it measurable, and generally measurability issues are dealt with by assuming the process is separable, so what I take from your comment is that the authors could have gone either way. Apologies for posting multiple questions.